# How to find representation of polynomial w.r.t different basis

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $B$ be the basis of the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2. $B = \{1, t-1,(t-1)^2\}$.

Let $u = 2t^2-5t+6$. How do you find $u_b$, the coordinate vector of $u$ relative to $B$? In particular, I'm looking how would you do this using matrices.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{B}= \left\{{ \begin{bmatrix}0t^2 \\ 0t \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},   \begin{bmatrix}0t^2 \\ 1t \\ -1 \end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}1t^2 \\ -2t \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}\right\}$$

This gives us the change of basis matrix:

$$\mathbf{B}  = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix} $$

which is invertible, because $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis and $\mathbf{B}$ is square:

$$\mathbf{B}^{-1}  = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

To convert a vector to your desired coordinate system, multiply the vector on the left by this matrix:

$$\left[{u}\right]_{\mathcal{B}} = \mathbf{B}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -5 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix} = \color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}} $$

Which is to say:

$$2t^2 -5t + 6 = \color{blue}{3} \color{blue}{-1}(t-1) + \color{blue}{2}(t-1)^2$$